# What is Google "Cloud Test Lab" and how we implemented in android

Tags: android, android-testing, android-instrumentation, google-developer-tools

I hear about Google **cloud test lab** from [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-test-lab/),what are the requirement for implementing our android app for cloud test lab? I tried sample app  but they written instrumental test-case and pass it to cloud,

- Any detail about implementation and requirement?
- what type of test it can perform?
- what about pricing?

Answer (score 0):

[Google Cloud Test lab](https://developers.google.com/cloud-test-lab/) basically runs an automated tests in accordance with your app's targeting criteria on several devices.

Cloud Test Lab can run [instrumentation tests](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests.html) that you write using [Espresso](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing.html) or [Robotium](http://robotium.com/pages/user-guide-android-studio). You can also use the Cloud Test Lab [Robo Test](https://developers.google.com/cloud-test-lab/robo-ux-test) to simulate user actions and find crashes in your app.

Clout Test Lab enables the user to run the tests during the development stages via [Android Studio](https://developers.google.com/cloud-test-lab/android-studio) and [Command line](https://developers.google.com/cloud-test-lab/command-line). You can also upload the apk to the [developer console](https://developers.google.com/cloud-test-lab/web-ui) and run a robo test or the user written instrumentation test on wide range of devices.

The test results can be found in the [developer console](https://developers.google.com/cloud-test-lab/analyzing-results) under particular project.

The [pricing details](https://developers.google.com/cloud-test-lab/pricing) are yet be announced by Google.